# can not access dlink 604 set up interface

Tags: router, ipv4

I used dlink－di604 enthernet board as router to share web access.

My ISP provides the service base on Ethernet rathern than base on Ethernet pppoe mode.

It is manually setup ipv4, subnet mask  , DNS, Gateway etc

Log in using web user name&password.

I use

```
http://192.168.0.2
```

try to access dlink di604 setup inferface, but failed

I call command

```
ipconfig /all
```

Dos shell displayed：

```
Ethernet adapter Local Connection:

Physical Address: 00-3c-56-79-19-49
IPv4 address:10.7.8.225
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
default gate way: 10.7.8.1
DNS servers 10.10.10.10
```

What is the correct way to access dlink 604 setup interface and set to share web access?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your proper local network address: The easiest way is to add a second IP address to your interface, that way you can access both the local network and the router while you configure it for your local network's IP standards. Open up the network adaptors control panel, get to the properties of your adaptor, make sure it's set as static, enter the advanced subscreen and add both your current IP (if it's not there now) and another IP on the DLink's subnet, such as 192.168.0.113. (Subnet must be 255.255.255.0) OK out of everything and you should be good to start configuring it, and once you're done, reset all of those settings back to the way they were.

If you're not on 10.* for any specific reason, or it's a work address that sticks around at home or whatever, you can set a single IP of 192.168.0.113 and set it back when you're done. I find it safer to add and then delete an address than always changing one though.